# ubuntu 18.04 apt-get upgrade problem "redirection loop encountered."

Tags: apt, 18.04

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. Now, when I run `apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error.

```
larry@VUbuntu15:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for larry: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libvte-2.91-0 linux-libc-dev
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,146 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://192.119.223.46:80/data/0116fed259cd0925/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libvte-2.91-0 amd64 0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
  Redirection loop encountered
Err:2 http://192.119.223.46:80/data/011634d2c0cdf482/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-30.32
  Redirection loop encountered
E: Failed to fetch http://192.119.223.46:80/data/0116fed259cd0925/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte2.91/libvte-2.91-0_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb  Redirection loop encountered
E: Failed to fetch http://192.119.223.46:80/data/011634d2c0cdf482/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-30.32_amd64.deb  Redirection loop encountered
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

If I run `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`, I get the same errors.

What does the "Redirection loop encountered" mean? How can I fix this error?

No problems with `apt-get update`. The `sources.list` file seems to be OK.

Answer (score 5):

You are going to love this.

192.119.223.46 resolves to 192-119-223-46.client.mchsi.com.

mchsi.com belongs to Mediacom.
If you are a Mediacom customer it means they are hijacking your traffic and sending it somewhere it shouldn't go.

I would try a traceroute to us.archive.ubuntu.com and see where it diverts.

I would also try using a free DNS server like Google's 8.8.8.8 or Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1.

Comment: Thanks, Peter:  I am a Mediacom customer, as you suspected.  However, the problem "miraculously" disappeared when I ran sudo apt-get upgrade the next day.  I suspect that the problem had something to do with the fact that the linux kernel upgrade was being held back.  It was evidently released yesterday, and the upgrade completed with no further problem.

Comment: Huh. This is my case as well. The IP in my case is 122.2.223.43, which upon reverse lookup resolves to 122.2.223.43.static.pldt.net. Can't trust these ISP's. Using a VPN solved this issue. This is freaky.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error.
I initially thought the message meant `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`until I tried`sudo apt-get upgrade--fix-missing`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

- Go to **software and updates**
- Under the **download from** drop-down menu,select **other**
- **Choose best server**
- After a while it will pick a server for you. **Choose server** and let it do the configuration.
- Then close and try to install, update or upgrade from the terminal.

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked for me.