# Installing Minecraft.deb. Tries to install but, gives a redirect loop

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, minecraft

Does anyone know why the official Minecraft.deb package is doing this to me?

> **smb@smb-Lenovo-H430:~$** sudo gdebi '/home/smb/Downloads/Minecraft.deb' Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree         Reading state information... Done
>   Reading state information... Done Requires the installation of the
>   following packages: gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common
>   libgconf-2-4 libpango-1.0-0 libpango1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
>   libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
>
> **Official Minecraft Launcher** Do you want to install the software package? [Y/N]:y
>   Err
>   http://172.83.31.249:80/data/03944c8ab24d9d8d/ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   bionic/universe amd64 gconf2-common all 3.2.6-4ubuntu1   Redirection
>   loop encountered
>                                                      Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                         > Error
>   during install: 'Failed to fetch
>   http://172.83.31.249:80/data/03944c8ab24d9d8d/ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  /pool/universe/g/gconf/gconf2-common_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_all.deb
>   *Redirection loop encountered*

Is the address down or something? Come to think of it, I seem to get this a lot when trying to install on Ubuntu. What am I doing wrong?

-SAM

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg -i` command?

Answer (score 1):

**A redirection loop** has nothing to do with Ubuntu. It means one of the following ([previous related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063364)):

- The mirror you have chosen is misconfigured
- Your ISP is hijacking traffic to that domain for it's own reasons

The solution is usually to select a different mirror and try again.

(Aside: You don't need gdebi to install a deb anymore. Apt will happily do it: `sudo apt install ./file_name.deb`)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I'm using a .deb package that came from the official Minecraft.net website, how do I choose a different domain when trying to install it?

Comment: I do not understand the comment: There are no 'domains' when installing anything in Ubuntu. If you are asking how to select a different mirror, then use the Search box at the top of every AskUbuntu page - it's been asked and answered many times..